# WIP "Console" processor, written in C#

Tags: python, c#

I decided I wanted to make a console-like system. So, I started planning & creating it in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23). Currently, all that it is is a processor of sorts. It reads all bytes from a file (`R:\disk00`), and then executes them, somewhat like a CPU. `display.pyw` is a simple [pygame](/questions/tagged/pygame) application which reads `R:\disk01` and displays the characters therein.
*(To run this, you need to have an `R:` drive mounted and at least `disk00` and `disk01` files. `disk01` should be 512 bytes long.)*

I've never actually done anything like this, so I'm proud of this project. Currently, though, I want it to be faster. Since eventually, I'll be creating full games in this, I need it to be fast. I've made it fairly fast, but I'm sure that it can be improved. Also, my code is normally overengineered, so I'm sure there's a bit I can improve.

This is my first post here so I'm hoping I didn't mess it up. Thanks!

```cs
// Program.cs
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace BarkleySRC
{
    class Program
    {
        public static long CMS()
        {
            return DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Processor Proc = new Processor();
            long time1 = CMS();
            Proc.begin("R:\\disk00");
            long time2 = CMS();

            double difference = time2 - time1;
            Console.WriteLine($"Finished in {difference/1000} seconds @ ~{Proc.registers[10] / (difference/1000)} ops/second\n");

            string[] registernames = new string[] { "EAX   ", "EBX   ", "ECX   ", "EDX   ",
                                                    "ESP   ", "EIP   ", "IAX   ", "IBX   ",
                                                    "EIX   ", "CPUFLG", "ETCX  " };

            for (int i = 0; i < Proc.registers.Length; i++)
                Console.WriteLine($"{registernames[i]}  " +
                    $"{Proc.registers[i].ToString("X").PadLeft(8, '0')}  " +
                    $"{Convert.ToString(Proc.registers[i], 2).PadLeft(32, '0')}");
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
// Processor.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading;

public class Processor
{
    Dictionary<int, uint> registerSegments = new Dictionary<int, uint>
            {
                { 0, 0xFFFFFF00 },
                { 1, 0xFFFF00FF },
                { 2, 0xFFFF0000 },
                { 3, 0x00000000 },
            };
    Dictionary<int, int> sizint_lengths = new Dictionary<int, int>
            {
                { 0, 1 },
                { 1, 2 },
                { 2, 2 },
                { 3, 4 },
            };
    Dictionary<int, int> sizint_bitshift = new Dictionary<int, int>
    {
        { 0, 0 },
        { 1, 8 },
        { 2, 0 },
        { 3, 0 },
    };

    public uint[] registers = new uint[]
    {
                // GENERAL PURPOSE REGISTERS
                0x00000000,  // EAX     0
                0x00000000,  // EBX     1
                0x00000000,  // ECX     2
                0x00000000,  // EDX     3
                // POINTER REGISTERS
                0x00000000,  // ESP     4
                0x00000000,  // EIP     5
                // INTERRUPT REGISTERS
                0x00000000,  // IAX     6
                0x00000000,  // IBX     7
                0x00000000,  // EIX     8
                // CPU RELATED
                0x00000000,  // CPUFLG  9
                0x00000000,  // ETCX   10
    };
    public uint[] cmp = new uint[2] { 0, 0 };
    public int interrupt = -1;

    /* Disknum : bytes */
    private Dictionary<int, byte[]> CachedDisks = new Dictionary<int, byte[]>();
    /* [segmentmin : segmentmax] : [Segments, disk] */
    private Dictionary<int[], int[]> DiskRanges = new Dictionary<int[], int[]>();
    bool quit = false;

    public async void begin(string path)
    {
        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

        while (!quit)
        {
            uint addr = registers[5];

            if (addr >= bytes.Length)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Access fault");
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }

            switch (bytes[addr])
            {
                case 0: registers[5]++; break;  // NOP
                case 0xFF: quit = true; break;  // QUIT

                case 0x20:  // CMPR
                    {
                        byte rbyte1 = bytes[addr + 1];
                        byte rbyte2 = bytes[addr + 2];
                        uint rval1 = registers[rbyte1 & 0b00111111]   // Get the unsegmented value of the register
                            & ~registerSegments[(rbyte1 & 0b11000000) >> 6];  // Segment register
                        uint rval2 = registers[rbyte2 & 0b00111111]   // Get the unsegmented value of the register
                            & ~registerSegments[(rbyte2 & 0b11000000) >> 6];  // Segment register
                        cmp[0] = rval1;
                        cmp[1] = rval2;
                        registers[5] += 3;
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x21:  // CMPI
                    {
                        byte rbyte = bytes[addr + 1];
                        uint rval = registers[rbyte & 0b00111111]   // Get the unsegmented value of the register
                            & ~registerSegments[(rbyte & 0b11000000) >> 6];  // Segment register
                        uint immn = Unsafe.As<byte, uint>(ref bytes[addr + 2]);
                        cmp[0] = rval;
                        cmp[1] = immn;
                        registers[5] += 6;
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x22:  // JMP
                    {
                        uint address = Unsafe.As<byte, uint>(ref bytes[addr + 1]);
                        registers[5] = address;
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x23:  // JE
                    {
                        if (cmp[0] == cmp[1])
                        {
                            registers[5] = Unsafe.As<byte, uint>(ref bytes[addr + 1]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            registers[5] += 5;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x24:  // JNE
                    {
                        if (cmp[0] != cmp[1])
                        {
                            registers[5] = Unsafe.As<byte, uint>(ref bytes[addr + 1]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            registers[5] += 5;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x25:  // JG
                    {
                        if (cmp[0] > cmp[1])
                        {
                            registers[5] = Unsafe.As<byte, uint>(ref bytes[addr + 1]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            registers[5] += 5;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x26:  // JGE
                    {
                        if (cmp[0] >= cmp[1])
                        {
                            registers[5] = Unsafe.As<byte, uint>(ref bytes[addr + 1]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            registers[5] += 5;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x27:  // JL
                    {
                        if (cmp[0] < cmp[1])
                        {
                            registers[5] = Unsafe.As<byte, uint>(ref bytes[addr + 1]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            registers[5] += 5;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x28:  // JLE
                    {
                        if (cmp[0] <= cmp[1])
                        {
                            registers[5] = Unsafe.As<byte, uint>(ref bytes[addr + 1]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            registers[5] += 5;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x30:  // SET
                    {
                        uint immn = Unsafe.As<byte, uint>(ref bytes[addr + 2]);
                        int sizint = (bytes[addr + 1] & 0b11000000) >> 6;
                        int regint = bytes[addr + 1] & 0b00111111;
                        registers[regint] &= registerSegments[sizint];
                        registers[regint] |= immn & ~registerSegments[sizint];
                        registers[5] += (uint)(2 + sizint_lengths[sizint]);
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x31:  // CLN
                    {
                        byte rbyte1 = bytes[addr + 1];
                        byte rbyte2 = bytes[addr + 2];
                        uint rval = registers[rbyte2 & 0b00111111]   // Get the unsegmented value of the register
                            & ~registerSegments[(rbyte2 & 0b11000000) >> 6];  // Segment register
                        registers[rbyte1 & 0b00111111] = registers[rbyte1 & 0b00111111]  // Get/set ungegmented value of the register
                            & registerSegments[(rbyte1 & 0b11000000) >> 6]  // Filter unwanted bits
                            | rval & ~registerSegments[(rbyte1 & 0b11000000) >> 6];  // OR in wanted bits
                        registers[5] += 3;
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x32:  // FTC
                    {
                        byte rbyte1 = bytes[addr + 1];
                        byte rbyte2 = bytes[addr + 2];
                        uint address = registers[rbyte2 & 0b00111111]   // Get the unsegmented value of the register
                            & ~registerSegments[(rbyte2 & 0b11000000) >> 6];  // Segment register

                        byte fetched = 0x00;

                        foreach (int[] _range in DiskRanges.Keys)
                        {
                            long num = (address / 512 - _range[0]) * (address / 512 - _range[1]);
                            if (num >= 0 && num <= 1)
                            {
                                address -= (uint)(512 * _range[0]);
                                if (address >= CachedDisks[DiskRanges[_range][1]].Length)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine($"Access fault @ {addr:X}");
                                    Environment.Exit(1);
                                }
                                fetched = CachedDisks[DiskRanges[_range][1]][address];
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (address >= bytes.Length)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine($"Access fault @ {addr:X}");
                                    Environment.Exit(1);
                                }
                                fetched = bytes[address];
                            }
                        }

                        registers[rbyte1 & 0b00111111] = fetched & ~registerSegments[(rbyte1 & 0b11000000) >> 6];  // OR in wanted bits
                        registers[5] += 3;
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x33:  // INC
                    {
                        byte rbyte = bytes[addr+1];
                        uint rval = registers[rbyte & 0b00111111];   // Get the unsegmented value of the register

                        uint targetval = rval & ~registerSegments[(rbyte & 0b11000000) >> 6];
                        rval &= registerSegments[(rbyte & 0b11000000) >> 6];
                        targetval >>= sizint_bitshift[(rbyte & 0b11000000) >> 6];
                        targetval++;
                        targetval <<= sizint_bitshift[(rbyte & 0b11000000) >> 6];

                        registers[rbyte & 0b00111111] = rval | targetval;
                        registers[5] += 2;
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x34:  // DEC
                    {
                        byte rbyte = bytes[addr + 1];
                        uint rval = registers[rbyte & 0b00111111];   // Get the unsegmented value of the register

                        uint targetval = rval & ~registerSegments[(rbyte & 0b11000000) >> 6];
                        rval &= registerSegments[(rbyte & 0b11000000) >> 6];
                        targetval >>= sizint_bitshift[(rbyte & 0b11000000) >> 6];
                        targetval--;
                        targetval <<= sizint_bitshift[(rbyte & 0b11000000) >> 6];

                        registers[rbyte & 0b00111111] = rval | targetval;
                        registers[5] += 2;
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x35:  // ADD
                    {
                        byte rbyte = bytes[addr + 1];
                        uint immn = Unsafe.As<byte, uint>(ref bytes[addr + 2]);

                        int sizint = (rbyte & 0b11000000) >> 6;
                        int regint = rbyte & 0b00111111;

                        uint rval = registers[regint];

                        immn <<= sizint_bitshift[sizint];
                        immn &= ~registerSegments[sizint];

                        rval += immn;

                        registers[regint] = rval;

                        registers[5] += 2 + (uint)sizint_lengths[sizint];
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x36:  // ADR
                    {
                        byte rbyte = bytes[addr + 1];
                        uint immn = registers[bytes[addr + 2] & 0b00111111];

                        int sizint = (rbyte & 0b11000000) >> 6;
                        int regint = rbyte & 0b00111111;

                        uint rval = registers[regint];

                        immn <<= sizint_bitshift[sizint];
                        immn &= ~registerSegments[sizint];

                        rval += immn;

                        registers[regint] = rval;

                        registers[5] += 3;
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x37:  // SUB
                    {
                        byte rbyte = bytes[addr + 1];
                        uint immn = Unsafe.As<byte, uint>(ref bytes[addr + 2]);

                        int sizint = (rbyte & 0b11000000) >> 6;
                        int regint = rbyte & 0b00111111;

                        uint rval = registers[regint];

                        immn <<= sizint_bitshift[sizint];
                        immn &= ~registerSegments[sizint];

                        rval -= immn;

                        registers[regint] = rval;

                        registers[5] += 2 + (uint)sizint_lengths[sizint];
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x38:  // SUBR
                    {
                        byte rbyte = bytes[addr + 1];
                        uint immn = registers[bytes[addr + 2] & 0b00111111];

                        int sizint = (rbyte & 0b11000000) >> 6;
                        int regint = rbyte & 0b00111111;

                        uint rval = registers[regint];

                        immn <<= sizint_bitshift[sizint];
                        immn &= ~registerSegments[sizint];

                        rval -= immn;

                        registers[regint] = rval;

                        registers[5] += 3;
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x39:  // NOT
                    {
                        byte rbyte = bytes[addr + 1];
                        uint rval = registers[rbyte & 0b00111111];
                        uint wval = rval & ~registerSegments[(rbyte & 0b11000000) >> 6];
                        rval &= registerSegments[(rbyte & 0b11000000) >> 6];
                        wval = ~wval;
                        rval |= wval & ~registerSegments[(rbyte & 0b11000000) >> 6];
                        registers[rbyte & 0b00111111] = rval;
                        registers[5] += 2;
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x3A:  // OR [r8 immn32]
                    {
                        byte rbyte = bytes[addr + 1];
                        uint immn = Unsafe.As<byte, uint>(ref bytes[addr + 2]);

                        int sizint = (rbyte & 0b11000000) >> 6;
                        int regint = rbyte & 0b00111111;

                        uint rval = registers[regint];

                        immn <<= sizint_bitshift[sizint];
                        immn &= ~registerSegments[sizint];

                        rval |= immn;

                        registers[regint] = rval;

                        registers[5] += 2 + (uint)sizint_lengths[sizint];
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x3B:  // OR [r8 r8]
                    {
                        byte rbyte = bytes[addr + 1];
                        uint immn = registers[bytes[addr + 2] & 0b00111111];

                        int sizint = (rbyte & 0b11000000) >> 6;
                        int regint = rbyte & 0b00111111;

                        uint rval = registers[regint];

                        immn <<= sizint_bitshift[sizint];
                        immn &= ~registerSegments[sizint];

                        rval |= immn;

                        registers[regint] = rval;

                        registers[5] += 3;
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x3C:  // AND [r8 immn32]
                    {
                        byte rbyte = bytes[addr + 1];
                        uint immn = Unsafe.As<byte, uint>(ref bytes[addr + 2]);

                        int sizint = (rbyte & 0b11000000) >> 6;
                        int regint = rbyte & 0b00111111;

                        uint rval = registers[regint];

                        immn <<= sizint_bitshift[sizint];
                        immn &= ~registerSegments[sizint];

                        rval &= immn;

                        registers[regint] = rval;

                        registers[5] += 2 + (uint)sizint_lengths[sizint];
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x3D:  // AND [r8 r8]
                    {
                        byte rbyte = bytes[addr + 1];
                        uint immn = registers[bytes[addr + 2] & 0b00111111];

                        int sizint = (rbyte & 0b11000000) >> 6;
                        int regint = rbyte & 0b00111111;

                        uint rval = registers[regint];

                        immn <<= sizint_bitshift[sizint];
                        immn &= ~registerSegments[sizint];

                        rval &= immn;

                        registers[regint] = rval;

                        registers[5] += 3;
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x3E:  // XOR [r8 immn32]
                    {
                        byte rbyte = bytes[addr + 1];
                        uint immn = Unsafe.As<byte, uint>(ref bytes[addr + 2]);

                        int sizint = (rbyte & 0b11000000) >> 6;
                        int regint = rbyte & 0b00111111;

                        uint rval = registers[regint];

                        immn <<= sizint_bitshift[sizint];
                        immn &= ~registerSegments[sizint];

                        rval ^= immn;

                        registers[regint] = rval;

                        registers[5] += 2 + (uint)sizint_lengths[sizint];
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x3F:  // XOR [r8 r8]
                    {
                        byte rbyte = bytes[addr + 1];
                        uint immn = registers[bytes[addr + 2] & 0b00111111];

                        int sizint = (rbyte & 0b11000000) >> 6;
                        int regint = rbyte & 0b00111111;

                        uint rval = registers[regint];

                        immn <<= sizint_bitshift[sizint];
                        immn &= ~registerSegments[sizint];

                        rval ^= immn;

                        registers[regint] = rval;

                        registers[5] += 3;
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x40:  // INT
                    {
                        short immn = Unsafe.As<byte, short>(ref bytes[addr + 1]);
                        interrupt = immn & 0xFFFF;
                        checkInterrupt();
                        registers[5] += 3;
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x41:  // I/O branch
                    {
                        registers[5]++;
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x42:  // LDSK
                    {
                        int disk = bytes[addr + 1];
                        if (!File.Exists("r:\\disk" + disk.ToString("X").PadLeft(2, '0')))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Disk fault @ {addr:X}");
                            Environment.Exit(1);
                        }
                        byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes("r:\\disk" + disk.ToString("X").PadLeft(2, '0'));
                        CachedDisks[disk] = buffer;
                        registers[5] += 2;
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x43:  // MEMRANGE
                    {
                        int disknum = bytes[addr + 1];
                        int segment0 = Unsafe.As<byte, int>(ref bytes[addr + 2]);
                        int segment1 = Unsafe.As<byte, int>(ref bytes[addr + 6]);

                        if (CachedDisks.ContainsKey(disknum))
                        {
                            DiskRanges[new int[] { segment0, segment1 }] = new int[] { segment1 - segment0, disknum };
                        }

                        registers[5] += 10;
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x44:  // STM
                    {
                        uint address = Unsafe.As<byte, uint>(ref bytes[addr + 2]);

                        if (DiskRanges.Keys.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (int[] _range in DiskRanges.Keys)
                            {
                                long num = (address / 512 - _range[0]) * (address / 512 - _range[1]);
                                if (num >= 0 && num <= 1)
                                {
                                    int disk = DiskRanges[_range][1];
                                    address -= (uint)(512 * _range[0]);
                                    if (address >= CachedDisks[disk].Length)
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine($"Disk Access fault @ {addr:X}");
                                        Environment.Exit(1);
                                    }
                                    CachedDisks[disk][address] = bytes[addr + 1];
                                    try
                                    {
                                        await File.WriteAllBytesAsync("r:\\disk" + disk.ToString("X").PadLeft(2, '0'), CachedDisks[disk]);
                                    }
                                    finally { }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    bytes[address] = bytes[addr + 1];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (address >= bytes.Length)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"Access fault @ {addr:X}");
                                Environment.Exit(1);
                            }
                            bytes[address] = bytes[addr + 1];
                        }

                        registers[5] += 6;
                        break;
                    }
                case 0x45:  // STM
                    {

                        byte rbyte = bytes[addr + 2];
                        uint address = registers[rbyte & 0b00111111]
                            & ~registerSegments[(rbyte & 0b11000000) >> 6];

                        if (DiskRanges.Keys.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (int[] _range in DiskRanges.Keys)
                            {
                                long num = (address / 512 - _range[0]) * (address / 512 - _range[1]);
                                if (num >= 0 && num <= 1)
                                {
                                    int disk = DiskRanges[_range][1];
                                    address -= (uint)(512 * _range[0]);
                                    if (address >= CachedDisks[disk].Length)
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine($"Disk Access fault @ {addr:X}");
                                        Environment.Exit(1);
                                    }
                                    CachedDisks[disk][address] = bytes[addr + 1];
                                    try
                                    {
                                        await File.WriteAllBytesAsync("r:\\disk" + disk.ToString("X").PadLeft(2, '0'), CachedDisks[disk]);
                                    }
                                    finally { Console.WriteLine("Diskwrite error");  }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    bytes[address] = bytes[addr + 1];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (address >= bytes.Length)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"Access fault @ {addr:X}");
                                Environment.Exit(1);
                            }
                            bytes[address] = bytes[addr + 1];
                        }

                        registers[5] += 3;
                        break;
                    }
                default:  // INVALID
                    Console.WriteLine($"Invalid opcode 0x{bytes[addr]:X}");
                    registers[5]++;
                    break;
            }
            registers[10]++;
        }
    }

    private void checkInterrupt()
    {
        switch (interrupt)
        {
            case 0x10:
                {
                    char print = (char)(registers[6] & 0x000000FF);
                    Console.Write(print.ToString());
                    break;
                }
        }
        interrupt = -1;
    }
}
```

```py
# display.pyw
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()

display = pygame.display.set_mode((480, 360))

displayfont = pygame.font.Font('consola.ttf', 18)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
    
    display.fill((0, 0, 0))
    
    with open("R:\\disk01", "rb") as videomem:
        try:
            contents = videomem.read()
        except:
            contents = bytes(b'')
    
    lines = [""]
    cl = 0
    for b in contents:
        if len(lines[cl]) >= 48:
            cl += 1
            lines.append("")

        if b >= 0x20 and b < 0x7F: 
            lines[cl] += chr(b)
        elif b == 0x0A:
            cl += 1
            lines.append("")
    # 
    # 48 x 20  
    # 

    i = 0
    for line in lines:
        display.blit(displayfont.render(line, True, (255, 255, 255)), (0, i*18))
        i += 1

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Looks nice. Fast && short view: 1) Split logic into more methods especially the repetitive code. 2) avoid `async void`, use `async Task`+`await`. 3) hardcoded paths to files in code, move it to constants 4) registers has names only in comments, you can add some properties like `public uint EAX { get => registers[0]; set => registers[0] = value }`, then use like `EAX++` in code to make it more friendly to read. 4) also you can create `enum` with opcodes. Make as less magic numbers in code as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: there is a plenty of code. This review is very much incomplete.

---

Some design choices are seriously dubious.

- The `EIP` register is not a general purpose register, and you'd be in a better shape using it as `EIP` rather than `registers[5]`.
- Many instructions modify the register value blindly: `registers[regint] = regval;`. It means that, say, `ADD` may affect a sensitive register, e.g. `ETCX` (which apparently is supposed to count execution cycles), or `EIP`. I doubt it is an intention. Yet again, some registers are not general purpose.
- Comparison instructions fill up two hidden registers (`cmp[0]` and `cmp[1]`), and leave it to jumps to examine them. This is quite unorthodox. Normally, they set certain flags in `CPUFLAGS` registers (which is BTW unused in this code). Notice that your design prevents other instruction to affect the control flow. Again, a standard approach is to let, say, arithmetical, or logical, instructions to also set flags. Much more flexible.
- Invalid opcode is usually not ignored, but raises an exception (not in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) sense, of course). Give a processor a chance to recover. BTW, planting an illegal instruction is a very common technique to implement breakpoints.
- Calls and returns are sorely missing.
- Integrating the disk cache into a processor simulator doesn't look comfortable. It is not the processor job to deal with cache.

---

- `case 0x44: // STM` and `case 0x45: // STM` have *huge* amount of duplication. Ditto `case 0x3e` and `case 0x3f`, etc. Factor out the common functionality.
- I strongly recommend to have an `Instruction` type, at least to bind the instruction length to an opcode. It is very unclear why such and such instruction takes advances `EIP` by such and such amount. As a side note, it is very beneficial to advance `EIP` *as soon as you can*. You will see it when it comes to calls and returns.
- As mentioned in the comments, avoid magic numbers.

---

I don't really understand the segmentation business, so no comments here.

Comment: Thank you! I will take these into consideration. And yeah, not checking the register before setting is a bit of a dumb move but hey, who can you trust more than the user? Right..?